# 200 Test Devices in iOS Developer Account

Tags: ios, testing, limit, device, udid

We have reached our 100 devices quota. We were planning to buy an individual iOS Dev Acct, but  we saw this article: http://www.macrumors.com/2013/08/16/apple-begins-allowing-200-test-devices-per-developer-account/

Is there anyone of you who has 200 device slots as of now? One of our managers is hesitant to purchase because he read that article. (And he saw more articles in the past few days.)

As of now, as far as I know, Apple has not made any official announcements regarding that as well.

Do you know if this is true? or just a hoax?

Thanks :)

Comment: put this on official Apple page... we cannot say anything about Apple... **voting for close**

Comment: An individual iOS ADC account costs $99.  You've almost spent more just talking about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked my account and it is still limited to 100 devices. If I were you, I would just wait a little while until this becomes official or proved to be just a hoax. Then make your decision as to how to act once it's proved one of the two things.

Comment: this should be comment... isn't it?